# Add an image to a cube face?

Tags: three.js

It's possible add an image to a cube face without change the base color of this?
I've trying this way but the base color turns black.

```
 var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
 loader.load( './img/arona.png', function ( texture ) {
 var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 8 , 8 , 8 );
 var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, color: 0xBC997A } );
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 scene.add( mesh );
 } );
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368200/displaying-background-colour-through-transparent-png-on-material/13547817#13547817

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the answer, i applied the code of the jsfiddle but currently the cube has color but the console is showing a warning: THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture marked for update but image is undefined. Can you help me please?

Comment: You are probably setting `texture.needsUpdate = true;`. Remove that line. The loader sets the flag for you after the texture loads.